# CodeIgniter CSRF failing on forms

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, csrf, codeigniter-3

**Note: This question is *not* about failing AJAX requests, it is about failing regular form submissions.**

I have enabled CSRF protection in CodeIgniter 3, using the following `config.php`:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_token_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
```

I am correctly using `form_open()` in form fields in order to automatically generate the required hidden fields containing the CSRF tokens. However, when I submit any form on my website it results in the "An Error Was Encountered - The action you have requested is not allowed." error.

Cookie settings:

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '';
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = FALSE;
```

Session settings:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 2592000; // one month in seconds
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Also, contrary to most questions about CI CSRF protection, CSRF tokens in my AJAX request **do** properly work by adding the following snippet to my initial JavaScript:

```
function getCookie(c_name) { // A javascript function to get the cookie value
    if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if(c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if(c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR){ // This function will attach "csrf_test_name" with all the request you are sending.
    if (options.type.toLowerCase() === "post") { // Required only if its a post method
        var csrf_token = getCookie("csrf_cookie_name");
        // initialize `data` to empty string if it does not exist
        options.data = options.data || "";

        // add leading ampersand if `data` is non-empty
        options.data += options.data?"&":"";

        // add _token entry
        options.data += "csrf_token_name=" + csrf_token;
    }
});
```

Any way to get my CSRF protection to work in form fields? Also, my `csrf_cookie_name` value in the cookie is different from the `csrf_token_name` value in the hidden HTML field, is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because CSRF token getting regenerated on each AJAX request. You can solve this issue by setting `$config['csrf_regenerate']` option to `FALSE` or you can **update csrf token on each AJAX request manually** using jquery or javascript.

Check this article for implementation : [When CodeIgniter’s CSRF Protection breaks your Ajax](http://www.johnkieken.com/when-codeigniters-csrf-protection-breaks-your-ajax/)

This [answer by PaulD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41403505/4419992) is also great.

Comment: But submitting a form is not an AJAX request, right?

Comment: @Stan : if you are submitting form normally and whole form is rebuilding again after form submit then it will not cause any issue.

Comment: But it does. I am using a normal form with `form_open()` to generate the CSRF hidden input fields. Submitting it normally without any AJAX requests. Still getting an error.

Comment: are you using form helper to build your form ? can you paste your form HTML code.

Comment: Yes, `form_open()` is from the form helper class. HTML code here: https://pastebin.com/raw/ykXP0fFG

Comment: Try these: https://pastebin.com/ykXP0fFG or https://codepaste.net/7jeyez

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this issue many times.It's one of those problems that annoys me :)) . The issue seems to be the fact that by making an ajax request to a certain controller regenerates the token so you send the token generated previously,thus causing a token mismatch.I solved my problem by disabling csrf_regenerate.I know it's not as secure but it gets things going.